# Powershell Image download Script - Duplicate Images names will not download

Tags: c#, powershell

Script works great in Powershell, but, if the original image name is a duplicate, it will not download. Does anyone know how to append a digit to the image name so that we can download duplicate image names?

Comment: Why not use `irm` [`Invoke-RestMethod`]? It'll save you 8-10 lines easily

Comment: Save 3 more lines of boiler plate by not using a function for LogWrite because it's only called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Test-Path` above `Move-Item` to see if the file exists.  Use the output of that as an If/Then to determine if you should append a number.  You could even have that try up to 5 times, say, by adding some increment to a counter and a while statement testing if that counter is over some limit, or you've found a test-path that returns false.